# If $A$ is a C*-algebra and $x\in\text{Inv}(A)$ self-adjoint and $\|x\|=\|x^{-1}\|=1$. Is $a\mapsto xax^{-1}$ isometric?

Tags: c-star-algebras, isometry

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra and $x\in A$ invertible and self-adjoint such that $\|x\|=\|x^{-1}\|=1$. Define a map $$\varphi_{x}\colon A\to A,\qquad \varphi_{x}(a):=xax^{-1}.$$ 
Is $\varphi_{x}$ an isometry? That is, $\|\varphi_{x}(a)\|=\|a\|$ for all $a\in A$.

I have proven that $x$ must be unitary and it is clear that $\|\varphi_{x}(a)\|\leq\|x\|\|a\|\|x^{-1}\|=\|a\|$. But I don't see why $\|a\|\leq\|\varphi_{x}(a)\|$.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Work the opposite way. $a=x^{-1}\varphi_x(a)x$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that! Appearently I don't even need that $x$ is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know that $x$ is unitary, you can proceed by showing that $\|ua\|=\|a\|$ for all unitaries $u\in A$ and all $a\in A$.  Indeed,
$$\|ua\|^2=\|a^*u^*ua\|=\|a^*a\|=\|a\|^2.$$
Similarly, we see that $\|au\|=\|a\|$, and thus $\|uau^*\|=\|a\|$.